# OpenGL ES2 for Android - Weird random juts

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

I'm just starting to learn OpenGL ES2 for Android, and have come across a weird problem where sometimes a weird jut will be rendered from my objects (see pic). This doesn't always happen, which is strange, so I'm wondering if anyone has any experience with this sort of thing and how to fix it.

http://img717.imageshack.us/i/device2h.png/

Comment: I found the problem. I was calling  GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, object.vertices()); with the wrong number of vertices. Divided the array size by 3 (for x,y,z) and now its working just fine ;) Here:s what is looks like : http://img695.imageshack.us/i/desertx.png/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here was that I was calling GLES20.glDrawArrays(type, first, count) with an incorrect count. Setting the variable correctly fixed it.